# best way to define right position if width is 100% and body has a border margin

Tags: html, width

I want to have a line of text on the right side of the website.

the width of the body is set to 100% and body also has a margin-left of 20px.

if I now set the width of the  to inherit and set text-align to "right". The line of text is slightly out of the right browser border. since also the margin of 20px gets passed along.

since I can't put widht= inherit - 20px or inherit - margin-left(ofbody)

whats the most elegant way to solve this problem?

thx again as always!

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:absolute` with `left:0px; right -20px;`.

(This is what I gather your problem is, although some example HTML and CSS would make your question clearer.)